# how to read data from api without any gem rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I want to read data from an API [ean](http://developer.ean.com/) without using any gem. What I want is when the user searches for a particular hotel then my query should return me a data from [ean](http://developer.ean.com/).

How can I go about this thing? and how/where do I add the api key and secret ?

Comment: why do you want to access the api without adding any gems? That doenst sound senseful...

Comment: I meant there is no gem for that particular api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform HTTP requests in Ruby using the [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) standard library.

Most people prefer to use third party Gems because they offer additional features or cleaner API, compared to Net::HTTP.
However, most of them is based on Net::HTTP itself.

Comment: is httparty https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty a gem which can be used to red from a remote api ?

Comment: Yes, HTTParty is an HTTP client based on Net::HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Its a soap API you can use savon to build your own class to access that api. YOu will find a screencast for savon here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/290-soap-with-savon I had a look at the documentation its pretty well documented.